# Why does this scoping example from ANSI Common Lisp not work as expected?

Tags: common-lisp, scoping

I'm new to lisp and going through *ANSI Common Lisp* by *Paul Graham* and one of the exercises is to define a function like apply where any number printed out before it returns will be printed by default in octal.

I tried the following:

```
(let ((*print-base* 8))
  (defun like-apply (&rest args)
    (apply #'apply args)))
```

But it didn't work as expected:

```
(like-apply #'princ '(8)); returns 8 8 (expecting 10 8)
```

The following however works:

```
(defun apply8 (&rest args)
  (let ((*print-base* 8))
    (apply #'apply args)))
```

Returns correctly:

```
(apply8 #'princ '(8)); returns 10 8 (as expected)
```

So my question is why does the second example work, but not the first one? Both seem to manipulate the `*print-base*` variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common Lisp uses let to bind both lexical and "special" (dynamic) variables. The behavior you expected was lexical and the behavior you observed was dynamic. The printer variables are all special, and so let creates a dynamic binding for them.

The printer variables are sometimes used in examples of why dynamic binding can be useful. For instance the fact that you can control the behavior of princ by binding *print-base* is enabled by dynamic binding, otherwise princ would reference the binding of *print-base* active when princ was defined.

This behavior is a major reason many Common Lisp programmers are adamant about the *earmuffs* naming convention for special variables. Note that defvar and defparameter both create special variables.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that so clearly and for the added tip about defparameter and defvar both creating special variables. It completely makes sense what it means when they are special now.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you observe is correct.

It will be instructive to compare

```
(let ((*print-base* 8))
  (defun f1 ()
    *print-base*))
```

with

```
(defun f2 ()
  (let ((*print-base* 8))
    *print-base*))
```

to discover that `(f1)` returns `10` while `(f2)` returns `8`.

This is because `*print-base*` is bound around the definition of `f1`, so it is `8` while `f1` is being *defined* but not while it is being *executed*.

Comment: I think I get it, since it's a special variable (from m-n's answer above), it has dynamic scope. That means in the first example, it goes back to some global default value that *print-base* has (which is 10 if nothing is changed). In the second example , it changes the value of *print-base* every time f2 is called. Thanks to both of you guys.